# "release.tar.gz" couldn't be decommpressed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to install fabric by following "http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_startedv2.html"

I executed below command

```
curl -L https://logs.hyperledger.org/sandbox/vex-yul-hyp-jenkins-2/fabric-verify-x86_64_1/5/release.tar.gz -o release.tar.gz 2> /dev/null;  tar -xvf release.tar.gz
```

However error message was returned.

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

How can I resolve it?

Comment: That url returns a 404.

Comment: @Ouroborus
Thank you for comment.
URL is available. According to wget, it returned 200.

[command]
sudo wget --spider -nv --timeout 60 -t 1 http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_startedv2.html

[return]
2017-05-01 07:56:23 URL: http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_startedv2.html 200 OK

Comment: I reported this at https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric and will post a follow-up comment here if/when I get any response

Comment: I think he means https://logs.hyperledger.org/sandbox/vex-yul-hyp-jenkins-2/fabric-verify-x86_64_1/5/release.tar.gz returns a 404

Comment: Are you using os x or ubuntu? My os x show same error.

Comment: @KoOhhashi Try "https://logs.hyperledger.org/sandbox/vex-yul-hyp-jenkins-2/fabric-binaries-x86_64/". It is new url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@sideshowbarker thank you very much! resolved!

This was solved by Hyperledger-fabric community. Due to some reason, link of release.tar.gz was disabled.